# Extract columns from array of string

Tags: java

I have an array of string

```
String[] outLines = ['1 2 3', '1 2 3', '1 2 3'];
```

What I want to do is extract all values of a certain column to a new array. For example, the first column array will contain `[1, 1, 1]`. The second column array will contain `[2, 2, 2]` etc.

My first though was to loop the string array, split every string using spaces and then add each value to its relevant column array.

I was wondering, is there a better way to do so? both performance and syntax wise.

Comment: Consider using a proper 2D array here to represent your grid of data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, my reading of the question is whether there is an alternative to converting the current input format to a 2D array before picking out the desired  column.

Comment: @polo-language that is correct. The given input is a 1D array as written. No way to change that.

Comment: @guygrinberger And why do you think you can leave out such an important constraint in your question?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose "I have an array of [given format]" is a pretty clear statement of problem constraint...

Answer (score 1):

Wow ! It been while since last time I found this kind of questions!, there are many ways you can achieve your answer, consider one of them as follow with only four line of code.

```html
String[] outLines = {"1 2 3", "1 2 3", "1 2 3"};
List<String[]> accumulator = new ArrayList<>();
Arrays.stream(outLines).map(o -> o.split(" ")).forEach(accumulator::add);
String[][] result = accumulator.toArray(String[][]::new);

//Validate the result
Arrays.stream(result).map(Arrays::stream).forEach(o -> {
  System.out.println();
  o.forEach(System.out::print);
});
```

You can also create a Collector and use the accumulator and combiner quit similar to what I wrote for you and reduce the answer to two line.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to *map* the column values from the `String` array. Java provides several implementations of `Map`. The most applicable (imo) is `LinkedHashMap` since it preserves insertion order. Split the line on whitespace, iterate; for each column retrieve the existing `List` from the `Map` (or add a new `List` if one does not already exist). Something like,

```
String[] outLines = { "1 2 3", "1 2 3", "1 2 3" };
Map<Integer, List<String>> alMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
List.of(outLines).forEach(s -> {
    String[] line = s.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        List<String> al = alMap.getOrDefault(i, new ArrayList<>());
        al.add(line[i]);
        alMap.put(i, al);
    }
});
for (int key : alMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(alMap.get(key));
}
```

Which outputs

```
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Interesting approach, though introducing List and Map definitely won't be a performance win. Especially since this solution requires maintaining the entire map in memory until the end, whereas the simpler array solution generates and tosses a single String[] for each row, plus one String[] for the result.

Comment: The content of the inner for loop may be `alMap.computeIfAbsent(i, k-> new ArrayList<>()). add(line[i]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static int[][] extract(String[] array) {
    int rows = array.length, cols = array[0].split("\\s+").length;
    int[][] matrix = new int[cols][rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        String[] s = array[i].split("\\s+");
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            matrix[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(s[j]);
    }
    return matrix;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] outLines = {"1 2 3", "1 2 3", "1 2 3"};
    int[][] output = extract(outLines);
    for (int[] row : output)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
```